# XSLT 1.0 Problems implementing a recursive template

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm quite new to XSLT and have been struggling with implementing a recursive template, which goes through multiple text nodes and searches for a match. When creating a recursive template i get an error message saying "Required item type of first operand of '/' is node(); supplied value has item type xs:string". I don't know how to select the multiple nodes as nodes, instead of a string.

Objective: I have multiple test nodes like

```
<Chain>1 3 4 7 20 50 72 ...</Chain>
```

I want to iterate through these nodes to look for a matching number. When this number is found, i need to select a substring of a parent's element attribute.

Here's part of the stylesheet with the recursive template:

```
<xsl:template match="/l:LandXML/h:HexagonLandXML/h:Point/h:PointCode">
<xsl:variable name="id2" select="../@uniqueID"/>
  <xsl:call-template name="tests">
  <xsl:with-param name="input" select="/l:LandXML/h:HexagonLandXML/h:PlanFeature/h:CoordGeom/h:Spline/h:Chain"/>
  <xsl:with-param name="id" select="$id2"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tests">
<xsl:param name="id"/>
<xsl:param name="input"/>
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="substring-before($input, ' ') = $id">
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(substring-before(substring-after($input/../@oID, '_'), '_'), '#')"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:call-template name="tests">
            <xsl:with-param name="input" select="substring-after($input, ' ')"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="id" select="$id"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

For a better understaning, a full XML and XSLT is here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTzd/17

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The error message is coming from Saxon, which is an XSLT 2.0 processor, so why are you restricting yourself to XSLT 1.0 facilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to find out if

```
<Chain>1 3 4 7 20 50 72 ...</Chain>
```

contains, say, `50`?

There is no need for a recursive template here. XPath string functions can do that just fine. For XPath 1.0, use

```
//Chain[contains(concat(' ', ., ' '), concat(' ', $val, ' '))]
```

where `$val` is `'50'`. The `concat()` makes sure that there are no partial matches and that matches at the start and end are being found.

For XPath 2.0 and up, you can use `tokenize()`.

```
//Chain[tokenize(., ' ') = $val]
```

Comment: But how do i catch the last value where there is no proceeding space char? With concat(' ', $id, ' ') i can catch the values in between the start and the end, but not the last one will not be found. With concat(' ', $id) i could catch a value of '5' and not '50'.

Comment: The last one will be found. Try it. (I've actually explained it in the text, too.)

Comment: Indeed it is found, thank you very much! Will have to re-read your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Your template in `<xsl:with-param name="input" select="substring-after($input, ' ')"/>` passes on a string value, a string value does not have a parent node, so you will have to store/pass on the original element as a separate parameter. Note that you at xsltfiddle have access (and are using it) to Saxon 9.8 HE, an XSLT 3 processor, where you might be able to avoid the hassle of using a recursive template by using e.g. `tokenize(Chain, ' ')[. = $id]` or similar.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Unfortunately i'm restricted to XSLT1.0, xsltfiddle is used  just for debugging the code.

Comment: @Arturs.E, if you want to debug XSLT 1 with xsltfiddle, it might be better to change the processor to XslCompiledTransform or MSXML as that way you get more precise error messages than using an XSLT 3 processor to debug XSLT 1 code.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!